# Why does a string_view comparison not consider equal memory addresses

Tags: c++, string-view

As the title states.

Why does a `std::string_view` comparison not consider equal memory addresses.

According to the standard and equally the implementation of MSVC's STL implementation which I checked. When comparing two string views, the possibility of them referencing the same string in memory appears to be ignored and their content gets compared anyway.

Why is it not considered to test if they do reference the same string?

Comment: That would be *implementation* details that are up to MS to implement. If they choose to add the optimization of checking whether they two string views reference the same address, they can. I'm not aware of anything in the standard that requires it.

Comment: Where did you read that it needs to compare pointers?
It only needs to compare lexicographic.
https://eel.is/c++draft/string.view.comparison#lib:basic_string_view,operator==

Comment: @Raildex I think that's the question they're asking, why doesn't the standard require the optimisation of skipping the lexical comparison when the string views point to the same data

Comment: If non-equal addresses is considered to be a typical case, there is no sense to add address comparison - that check would be a pessimization.

Comment: Introducing an additional branch potentially penalizes the performance of the code path that is more common by far. Admittedly, the performance hit is really small compared to the performance of a string comparison, but is still a non-zero hit. If a program expects to encounter a lot of same-pointer cases for a specific task, then the comparison could easily be wrapped with this optimization.

Comment: A related query: Why does `hash` of a `string_view` hash the actual contents, rather than the tuple `{pointer, size}`? Is there any other view class I don't know about, that uses such pointer semantics for compare and hash?

Comment: Context of why this could be helpful: I am writing an algorithm that requires making multiple `string_view`s of the **same string**, and store/compare intermediate results (say, using a map). In such a case, comparing/hashing the actual `string_view` contents is entirely wasteful, especially for very long strings.

Comment: @crazyGamer For a hash to be a hash, hash(A) must always be the same at any point in time. After unknown amount of time the content of the string might have changed even though the position of the view has not. Would view A still be considered equal to our view A from before? I think the general consensus is that they are not the same anymore.
The analogy would be comparing a pointer from a minute ago to a pointer you have now. the object may have already been modified. Now you might find that to be okay but it's important not to forget the thing you're actually comparing.

Comment: Furthermore, a string_view is meant to be a view into a string. So naturally a lot of people would expect this to hold true: hash(string_view(A)) == hash(string(A)). It would be odd if that wasn't the case.